# how to work on BUY NOW button in android?

Tags: android, magento

I am developing an Android eCommerce application in which there are two different buttons. The first one is an **ADD TO CART** button and the other one is a **BUY NOW** button.

When I click on the **ADD TO CART** button, it successfully places the item in the cart and after I click on the cart button, the app proceeds to the Cart Activity. I did the same for **BUY NOW** but the issue is how do I update my cart and move to Cart Activity on a single click?

**ProductDescription.java:**

```
package com.www.prashant;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ProductDescription extends Fragment {

    View V;
    int position;
    ImageView product_image;
    TextView product_desc;
    public TextView price;
    public TextView specialPrice;
    TextView product_name;
    ImageLoader image;
    SliderLayout product_images;
    Button sharbtn;
    public TextView txt_qty;
    public Button btn_plus;
    public Button btn_buy;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    public int sum=0;
    public int remove=0;
    String cartMessage;
    String cartMessage1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        Constants.lastDetails = true;
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_details, container, false);

        //Set Navigation mode as Statndard
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        V=v;
        //get Product Position
        position = Constants.product_position;

        //Initialize ids
        product_image=(ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        product_desc=(TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textProductDescription);
        price=(TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        specialPrice = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textSpecialPrice);
        product_name=(TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textProductName);
        //sharbtn=(Button)V.findViewById(R.id.sharbtn);
        image=new ImageLoader(getActivity());
        image.DisplayImage(Constants.Product_image.get(position), product_image);

        product_name.setText(Constants.Product_name.get(position));
        product_desc.setText(Constants.Product_desc.get(position));
       // product_adesc.setText(Constants.Product_adesc.get(position));
        if(Constants.Product_specialPrice.get(position) < Constants.Product_price.get(position)
                && Constants.Product_specialPrice.get(position)!=0){
            price.setText(String.format("%.2f",Constants.Product_price.get(position)));
            price.setPaintFlags(price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            specialPrice.setText(String.format("%.2f",Constants.Product_specialPrice.get(position)));
        }
        else {
            price.setText(String.format("%.2f",Constants.Product_price.get(position)));
            specialPrice.setText(null);
        }

        btn_plus = (Button) V.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
        btn_buy = (Button) V.findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
       // btn_minus = (ImageButton) V.findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
        txt_qty = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.txt_qty);

        txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(Constants.Product_qty.get(position)));

        **/* Button Click Listener for Add Qty*/**
        btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Constants.Product_pos=position;
                remove=0;
                sum = Integer.parseInt(txt_qty.getText().toString())+1;
                Constants.Product_qty.set(position, sum);
                cartMessage1="Adding product to cart...";
                cartMessage="Product was added successfully";
                new updateCart().execute();
            }
        });

         **/* Button Click Listener for Buy Qty*/**

        btn_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Constants.Product_pos=position;
                remove=0;
                sum = Integer.parseInt(txt_qty.getText().toString())+1;
                Constants.Product_qty.set(position, sum);
                cartMessage1="Adding product to cart...";
                cartMessage="Product was added successfully";
                new updateCart().execute();

            }




        });


        product_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageFragment imageFrag=new ImageFragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content,imageFrag,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                getActivity().setTitle("Images");
            }
        });

        return v;
    }




    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).resetActionBar(true, DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            MainActivity.getInstance().CallFragment(Constants.position);
        }
        return true;
    }



    //Add product to cart task
    public class updateCart extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (pdialog==null){
                pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdialog.setMessage(cartMessage1);
                pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background

               parseJSONDataAddProductToCart();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (pdialog.isShowing()){
                pdialog.dismiss();
                pdialog=null;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cartMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Update Notification Count in action bar icon
            //Constants.cart_count += 1;
            //txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            MainActivity.getInstance().updateHotCount(Constants.ProductCart_Id.size());
            txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(Constants.Product_qty.get(position)));
            // if internet connection and data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text

        }
    }

    //Remove product from cart
    public class removeCartProduct extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (pdialog==null){
                pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdialog.setMessage(cartMessage1);
                pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background

            parseJSONDataAddProductToCart();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (pdialog.isShowing()){
                pdialog.dismiss();
                pdialog=null;
            }

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cartMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Update Notification Count in action bar icon
            //Constants.cart_count -= 1;
            //txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            MainActivity.getInstance().updateHotCount(Constants.ProductCart_Id.size());
            txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(Constants.Product_qty.get(position)));
            // if internet connection and data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text

        }
    }

    public void parseJSONDataAddProductToCart(){

        try {

            SoapObject item = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntity");
            SoapObject request;
            int qty;
            if(remove==0){
                request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductAdd");
                qty=1;

            }else{
                qty= Constants.Product_qty.get(Constants.Product_pos);
                if(qty==0){
                    request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductRemove");
                }else{

                    request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductUpdate");
                }
            }

            // add paramaters and values
            request.addProperty("sessionId", Constants.sessionId);
            PropertyInfo pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
            pinfo.setName("product_id");
            pinfo.setValue(Constants.Product_ID.get(Constants.Product_pos));
            pinfo.setType(String.class);
            item.addProperty(pinfo);

            pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
            pinfo.setName("qty");
            pinfo.setValue(qty);
            pinfo.setType(Double.class);
            item.addProperty(pinfo);

            SoapObject EntityArray = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
            EntityArray.addProperty("products", item);
            request.addProperty("quoteId", Constants.cartId);
            request.addProperty("products",EntityArray);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Web method call
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
            //get the response
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();

            Constants.CartaddStatus=result.toString();
            if(Constants.CartaddStatus == "true"){
                if (Constants.ProductCart_Id.isEmpty()){
                    Constants.cartArrayPos=0;
                }
                if (!Constants.ProductCart_Id.contains(Constants.Product_ID.get(Constants.Product_pos))) {

                    Constants.ProductCart_Id.add(Constants.cartArrayPos,Constants.Product_ID.get(Constants.Product_pos));
                    Constants.ProductCart_Img.add(Constants.cartArrayPos,Constants.Product_image.get(Constants.Product_pos));
                    Constants.ProductCart_Price.add(Constants.cartArrayPos, Constants.Product_price.get(Constants.Product_pos));
                    Constants.cartArrayPos+=1;
                }
                if (qty==0){
                    Constants.ProductCart_Id.remove(Constants.Product_pos);
                    Constants.ProductCart_Img.remove(Constants.Product_pos);
                    Constants.ProductCart_Price.remove(Constants.Product_pos);
                    Constants.cartArrayPos-=1;

                }
            }


        }  catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**ActivityCart:**

```
package com.www.prashant;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

/**
 * Created by Prashant on 10/16/2016.
 */
public class ActivityCart extends Fragment {
    int run;
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    View v;
    GridView list2;
    CartImageLoadAdapter adapter;
    public static ActivityCart sActivityCart;
    public Double TotalPrice= 0.00;
    TextView btn_place_order;
    TextView btn_place;
    Button btn_place_ord;
    static String TotalProductCartPrice;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart, container, false);

        sActivityCart = this;

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        list2=(GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.cartlist);
        //list2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        //list2.setVerticalSpacing(1);
      //  list2.setHorizontalSpacing(1);
        clearData();
        btn_place_order = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_place_order);
       // btn_place = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_place);
        btn_place_ord = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_place_ord);
        btn_place_ord.setOnClickListener(listener);

        return v;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Constants.lastDetails = false;
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        Constants.cartEntry=1;
        new getDataTask().execute();


    }

    void clearData(){
        Constants.Product_ID.clear();
        Constants.Product_name.clear();
        Constants.Product_price.clear();
        Constants.Product_image.clear();
        Constants.Product_qty.clear();
        Constants.Product_specialPrice.clear();
        Constants.Product_desc.clear();
        //Constants.Product_adesc.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Remove adapter refference from list
        if (run==1) {
            list2.setAdapter(null);
            //Refresh cache directory downloaded images
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //Click Listner for place order button
    public View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(run == 1) {

                // Call Login Function
                if(Constants.Customer_FirstName.equals(""))
                {
                    CartLogin CartLogin=new CartLogin();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content,CartLogin,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    getActivity().setTitle("Login");
                }
                else {
                    // Call Shipping Information Function
                    ActivityCustomerAddress CustomerAddress=new ActivityCustomerAddress();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content,CustomerAddress,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    getActivity().setTitle("Shipping");
                }
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cart is Empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };




    // Image urls used in LazyImageLoadAdapter.java file

    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (pdialog==null){
                pdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
                pdialog.setCancelable(false);
                pdialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background

            if (!Constants.ProductCart_Id.isEmpty()){
                parseJSONData();
                run=1;
            }else{
                run=0;
            }

            //Get Product Prices
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Create custom adapter for listview
            if (run==1) {
                String[] images = new String[Constants.Product_image.size()];
                images = Constants.Product_image.toArray(images);
                adapter = new CartImageLoadAdapter(getActivity(), images);

                //Set adapter to listview
                list2.setAdapter(adapter);

                if (pdialog.isShowing()) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();
                    pdialog = null;
                }
            }else{

                if (pdialog.isShowing()) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();
                    pdialog = null;
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Cart is Empty").setMessage("Start Shopping now !!").create().show();
                run=0;
            }
            // if internet connection and data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text
           // btn_place_order.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f   Place Order", TotalPrice));
            btn_place_order.setText(String.format("%.2f  ", TotalPrice));
            TotalProductCartPrice= btn_place_order.getText().toString();

        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Create URL string
        String URL = "http://prashant.com/customApi/cartDetails.php?cartId="+Constants.cartId;
        //Log.i("httpget", URL);
        JSONParser parser =new JSONParser();
        try
        {
            String SetServerString = "";

            // Create Request to server and get response

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            Constants.Login=SetServerString;
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(SetServerString);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
                Constants.Product_ID.add(Long.parseLong(obj.getString("productId")));
                Constants.Product_name.add(obj.getString("name"));
                Double price= Double.valueOf(obj.getString("price"));
                int Qty= Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("qty"));
                Constants.Product_price.add(price*Qty);
                Constants.Product_image.add(obj.getString("imageurl"));
                Constants.Product_qty.add(Integer.valueOf(obj.getString("qty")));
                Constants.Product_specialPrice.add((Double.valueOf(obj.getString("spprice")))*Qty);

                // Total Sum of Cart Item price
                TotalPrice += Double.valueOf(Double.valueOf(obj.getString("spprice"))*Qty);

            }

            // Show response on activity
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public static ActivityCart getInstance() {
        return sActivityCart;
    }

    public void SyncCart(){
        // Call Shipping Information Function
        ActivityCart SyncCart=new ActivityCart();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content,SyncCart,null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        getActivity().setTitle("Cart");
    }

}
```

Comment: call different webservices for ADD TO CART and after click on cart which will redirect you to cart activity. So you can easily call both the services for BUY NOW button. When you call BUY nOW first it will calll add to card and after that on post execute it will call click on cart service.